# Select windows in tmux using the numeric keypad

Tags: keyboard

I'd like to use the numeric keypad to select windows in tmux. Anybody do this?

Comment: Try reading the man pages and look at the key binding commands in tmux

Comment: This is technically on topic here, but you may be more likely to get an answer on unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 3):

If your terminal emulator outputs certain codes for the keypad keys, then these commands (e.g. in your `.tmux.conf`) will bind <kbd>Keypad 0</kbd>–<kbd>Keypad 9</kbd> to work exactly like <kbd>prefix</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>–<kbd>prefix</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>:

```
bind-key -n KP0 select-window -t :0
bind-key -n KP1 select-window -t :1
bind-key -n KP2 select-window -t :2
bind-key -n KP3 select-window -t :3
bind-key -n KP4 select-window -t :4
bind-key -n KP5 select-window -t :5
bind-key -n KP6 select-window -t :6
bind-key -n KP7 select-window -t :7
bind-key -n KP8 select-window -t :8
bind-key -n KP9 select-window -t :9
```

The `-n` means that you do not have to use the prefix key; the key names (`KPx`) do not seem to be in the documentation, but you can find them in the source in the file [`key-string.c`](http://tmux.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=tmux/tmux;a=blob;f=key-string.c;h=df177399240ce301b0b2fe121bbe04375d70e83e;hb=HEAD#l76). They values your terminal must send seem to be hard-coded: see [`tty-keys.c`](http://tmux.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=tmux/tmux;a=blob;f=tty-keys.c;h=681f31b6e535e2aee05c9ba15a524d2cd427b1fb;hb=HEAD#l60); TTYKEY_RAW means that terminfo is not used, and there are no other entries for the KEYC_KP* keys without TTYKEY_RAW (where terminfo might be consulted; the problem here is that terminfo support for the numeric keypad seems to be incomplete).

You can check whether your terminal emulator sends special codes for the keys by running this outside *tmux*:

```
tput smkx;cat -v;tput rmkx
```

(use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to end the `cat` instance)

You should probably see something like this for KP0–KP9:

```
^[Op^[Oq^[Or^[Os^[Ot^[Ou^[Ov^[Ow^[Ox^[Oy
```

This works for me by default in *iTerm2* (Build 1.0.0.20120724), but in *Terminal* (Version 2.3 (309); from OS X 10.8.2) I had to enable *Allow VT100 application keypad mode* for a profile (**Terminal** menu > **Preferences…**; **Settings** tab > *select a profile* > **Advanced** tab; check *Allow VT100 application keypad mode* under **Emulation**).

Comment: I use iTerm 2 (Build 3.2.9) I had to enable "Allow application keypad mode" in Preferences > Profile > Keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you have numlock enabled, the keypad sends the same input to the terminal as the number keys above the qwerty letters, so there's no way to specify the keypad specifically.  You can try to map the non-numlocked inputs from the keypad, but I think that's specific to your keyboard and terminal.

To map a key without requiring <kbd>Prefix</kbd>, use `bind-key -n key command`.  The `-n` stands for "normal mode".  So the commands that you likely want to add are:

```
bind-key -n 0 select-window -t 0
bind-key -n 1 select-window -t 1
bind-key -n 2 select-window -t 2
bind-key -n 3 select-window -t 3
bind-key -n 4 select-window -t 4
bind-key -n 5 select-window -t 5
bind-key -n 6 select-window -t 6
bind-key -n 7 select-window -t 7
bind-key -n 8 select-window -t 8
bind-key -n 9 select-window -t 9
```

Comment: Thanks. I used to do with with Linux and emacs way back when. Maybe I'll figure it out someday.

Comment: Could you explain a little more about what you're trying to do?  I'd be happy to help you figure it out.

Comment: The idea is that I could use the numbers on the numeric keypad to switch between tmux windows, without doing the tmux prefix command first.